# IBM Mobile first hybrid Interactive notifications iOS

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm having problem with interactive notifications on iOS.

As it is specified [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_interactive_notifications.html), I'm using WL.Client.Push.getInteractivePushCategories method to obtain categories. When notification arrives and I slide down to show buttons everything is working fine, but I can't see any place to specify actions for buttons. I need action to run without logging in to my application. Where is the right place to specify that actions?

Answer (score 0):

To specify actions, see the documentation here: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/notifications/handling-push-notifications/interactive/

However note that I believe you cannot do this without first logging-in to the application, as the push is sent for a specific user and this will require you to first login to the application, as with a regular notification, assuming you are sending an authenticated notification.

Comment: I needed only login at first time to authenticate user, and after that I was able to receive notifications with action buttons. (After adding in MyAppDelegate `- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo completionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler {` , but now I have problem that buttons not showing. (I have specified categories, and sending notification with category). Notification arriving but pull down, or swip left to see buttons not showing anything. Any Idea?